# What's the impact of eager_load=true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to know why `eager_load` is preferred to be `false` in non-production environments? One of the arguments that I have heard of says that `eager_load` eager loads most of Rails and application in memory. Hence using eager_load for individual test makes it run slower. However this raises some questions like how does a test run without loading Rails and application related code? What is the Rails and application related code that is being eager loaded? `config.eager_load_namespaces` gives the following classes:

```
ActiveSupport
ActionDispatch
ActiveModel
ActionView
ActionController
ActiveRecord
ActionMailer
Jquery::Rails::Engine
MyApp::Application
```

Are all of these classes and their subclasses being eager loaded?

What are the clear disadvantages of using `eager_load = false`  in development or testing environment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> However this raises some questions like how does a test run without loading Rails and application related code?

The test loads the necessary code on demand as it tries to use it.
So for example on some code line the test wants to use the `ActiveRecord` class. With `eager_load` set to `false` this class is not required yet, which will lead to an exception on a vanilla ruby program. Within a rails project however the test will require `ActiveRecord` on demand as it uses it. So at the end a single test runs faster, because only the code parts it needed have been required.

This technique is the opposite of eager loading and it's called [autoloading](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html)

> What is the Rails and application related code that is being eager loaded?

Check out https://github.com/rails/rails. It's a bunch of stuff.

> Are all of these classes and their subclasses being eager loaded?

yes

> What are the clear disadvantages of using eager_load = false in development or testing environment?

In development environment it's an advantage and a best practice as you get faster boot times (neglected when using a preloader like spring). Probably it's also easier for reloading changes along with the `cache_classes=false` option, as you have less to reload (just an assumption).

In test environment sometimes you just can't use `eager_load=false` if you want to estimate some code metrics 
like code coverage or doing style checks. E.g. `simple_cov` requires you to eager load all the code before starting tests.

And in general it can happen that some library can't be used with eager loading because it does some initialization on loading a class which has to be already available even before calling its methods. However this is a rare case, having said that, it happened to us with the `neo4j.rb` gem

Comment: ruby's autoload is quite separate from what is used for application code in development (although it is used for framework code)

Comment: I should mention eager_loading in test.rb caused our test suite to jump from 75.xx% coverage to 83.xx% coverage. Turned out, code ran while loading the files(like reading class and method definitions) was also considered by simplecov.

Comment: You mentioned that there are some libraries that can't be used with eager loading, could you please provide more details how you figured out it was that neo4j specific gem? what was the kind of error you were getting?

Comment: its 8 years ago :), but i guess something will be nil or unudefined and you get an according excpetion that method x cant be called on nil with according line. I dont remember exactly why state was not initialized and probably one could have just loaded that state in a rails initializer separetely without dumping eagaer_loading completly

Answer (score 1):

Eager load makes rails load all of your app on startup which increases startup time.

For example if you just want to load the rails console to check the behaviour of one model then you have to wait for all of the models, controllers etc. to load even though you only wanted to use one of them

Comment: This is correct, however it does not addresses the authors questions completely