# Rails 5: rails s production with config.eager_load=true fails while gem 'gem_name', require: false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, gemfile

I've been struggling to deploy an application in production with `config.eager_load = true`.

I know this configuration loads most of Rails and application code in memory, and it's a nice feature to have in production(like) environments, the problem is that i have a custom rails engine with some code that is used only on certain modules of my main application code and it's only required on certain files.

My custom engine is installed like this in *Gemfile*:

`gem 'gem_name', require: false`

and required in files like this:

`require 'gem_name'`

So, when i run **`rails s -e production`** (which has config.eager_load=true activated) it fails automatically with the following error

> bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `load': No
>   such file to load (LoadError)

Any ideas on how to make eager_load work when a gem is not required on *Gemfile*?

`gem 'gem_name', require: false`

And what problems could i have if i set eager_load to false on production(like) environments?

Comment: Are you sure that this error is because of that `gem 'gem_name' ` ? If your eager_load is false then every user loads new instance of an app I guess. What are advantages of using require: false ? When you use eager_load it load all needed files at the start and keep it in memory so it doesn't have to load with each user.

Comment: Yes, `require: false` and `config.eager_load=true` combination causes the error, i use `require: false` to manually require the gem only when i need the gem functionality, this is because that gem has classes that can conflict with my application classes, and gem has classes with same names that some of my application models. Can you please explain with more detail about eager loading with each user? I didn't know this was the proper functionality of eager_load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched for a bit, try upating bootsnap gem, try delete 'bootsnap-load-path-cache' and 'bootsnap-compile-cache'  from tmp/cache folder. 
This article May help understand eager load  https://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/

This topic may help understand
[What's the impact of eager_load=true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833647/whats-the-impact-of-eager-load-true)

it points to other solution, not require but autoload(http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html)

**From the guides(please read)**:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths-and-eager-load-paths

Comment: Thanks sonic, i finally understood what autoload and eager load really does, all the information was very helpful, nice and clear, what i ended up doing was autoloading each file instead of requiring it.
For those that need to autoload all files inside a directory, you can do this:
Dir.glob(File.join(some_path, 'app', 'models', '*.rb')).map do |file|
  autoload File.basename(file).gsub('.rb', '').classify.to_sym, file
end

Great answer!

Comment: Im happy to hear that !!! For me this topic of autoload is also new, thanks to you I learned something new also ;)

Answer (score 0):

For those that need to autoload all files inside a directory instead of requiring them, you can do this:

`Dir.glob(File.join(some_path, 'lib', 'extensions', '*.rb')).map do |file|
  autoload File.basename(file).gsub('.rb', '').classify.to_sym, file
end`

instead of the classic

`Dir[File.join(some_path, 'lib', 'extensions', '*.rb')].each do |f|
  require f
end`